# Contact permissions problem in android manifest

Tags: android, permissions, contacts

I need to set the permission in the manifest to read, I manually edited the manifest after having problems trying to use the android manifest editor. My code is below and is currently proving to be erroneous. Any help appreciated. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ac.uk.d"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Quiz"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: what kind of error are you getting? There nothing seams to be out of order (as far as you have a `Quiz.java` class in your `ac.uk.d` package!). If you have the `ac.uk.d.Quiz.java`, you should try to clean your project (make a clean build).

Comment: You were on the money, hitting clean project sorted it out perfectly! I was quite sure there was nothing wrong with it, though it did take me about 5 minutes to figure out how to clean the project, so for anyone reading this just hit 'Project' on the top menu bar there you will find clean. Thank you for your help rekaszeru

Comment: ;) you're welcome! Also - to mark this question solved -, if you've found the solution, should write an answer, and accept it, so others can learn from it.

Comment: Right, thanks... I wasn't sure what to do haha.. still a noobie here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have not cleaned the project. To clean the project, select 'Project' on the top menu bar then you'll find clean upon which you clean the selected project or clean all projects as per your needs..